# postgresql: DB connection was unexpectedly closed while running local chainlink node

Tags: postgresql, chainlink

I have been trying to run a local chainlink node in Windows 10, WSL1 - Ubuntu Distribution and postgresql 14.5. I am running the following command from WSL shell:

```
chainlink local n
```

But, I am getting the following error, displaying that db connection was unexpectedly closed:

```
DB connection was unexpectedly closed; checking out a new one pg/advisory_lock.go:178          advisoryLockID=1027321974924625846 err=sql: connection is already closed logger=1.10.0@9b1c622.RunNode.LockedDB.AdvisoryLock
2022-12-13T13:31:48.986+0530 [DEBUG] Taking advisory lock                               pg/advisory_lock.go:132          advisoryLockID=1027321974924625846 logger=1.10.0@9b1c622.RunNode.LockedDB.AdvisoryLock
2022-12-13T13:31:48.988+0530 [FATAL] Another node has taken the advisory lock, exiting immediately pg/advisory_lock.go:191
```

I have tried to set env variables in postgresql.conf file:

```
listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' # comma-separated list of directories
                                        # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''                 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777         # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                                        # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off                          # advertise server via Bonjour

tcp_keepalives_idle = 60                # TCP_KEEPIDLE, in seconds;
                                        # 0 selects the system default
tcp_keepalives_interval = 60            # TCP_KEEPINTVL, in seconds;
                                        # 0 selects the system default
tcp_keepalives_count = 10               # TCP_KEEPCNT;
                                        # 0 selects the system default
tcp_user_timeout = 120                  # TCP_USER_TIMEOUT, in milliseconds;
                                        # 0 selects the system default
```

pg_hba.conf file

```
listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' # comma-separated list of directories
                                        # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''                 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777         # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                                        # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off                          # advertise server via Bonjour
```

Precise Terminal Output:

```
 Listening and serving HTTP on port 6688            cmd/client.go:460                logger=1.10.0@9b1c622
2022-12-13T13:31:48.110+0530 [DEBUG] Fetching head                                      headtracker/head_tracker.go:331  blockHeight=29636533 evmChainID=80001 logger=1.10.0@9b1c622.EVM.HeadTracker
2022-12-13T13:31:48.111+0530 [DEBUG] RPC call: evmclient.Client#CallContext             client/node.go:426               args=["0x1c437b5",false] evmChainID=80001 logger=1.10.0@9b1c622.EVM.Node.RPC method=eth_getBlockByNumber mode=websocket node=(primary)primary-0-80001:wss://polished-divine-owl.matic-testnet.discover.quiknode.pro/API_KEY/ nodeName=primary-0-80001 nodeTier=primary requestID=a3f6a25f-9052-4382-bf2c-6b99a7ffe8b6
2022-12-13T13:31:48.321+0530 [DEBUG] evmclient.Client#CallContext RPC call success      client/node.go:945               args=["0x1c437b5",false] callName=CallContext duration=0.2088953 evmChainID=80001 logger=1.10.0@9b1c622.EVM.Node.RPC method=eth_getBlockByNumber mode=websocket node=(primary)primary-0-80001:wss://polished-divine-owl.matic-testnet.discover.quiknode.pro/API_KEY/ nodeName=primary-0-80001 nodeTier=primary requestID=a3f6a25f-9052-4382-bf2c-6b99a7ffe8b6 rpcDomain=polished-divine-owl.matic-testnet.discover.quiknode.pro
2022-12-13T13:31:48.325+0530 [DEBUG] Fetching head                                      headtracker/head_tracker.go:331  blockHeight=29636532 evmChainID=80001 logger=1.10.0@9b1c622.EVM.HeadTracker
2022-12-13T13:31:48.326+0530 [DEBUG] RPC call: evmclient.Client#CallContext             client/node.go:426               args=["0x1c437b4",false] evmChainID=80001 logger=1.10.0@9b1c622.EVM.Node.RPC method=eth_getBlockByNumber mode=websocket node=(primary)primary-0-80001:wss://polished-divine-owl.matic-testnet.discover.quiknode.pro/API_KEY/ nodeName=primary-0-80001 nodeTier=primary requestID=REQUEST_ID
2022-12-13T13:31:48.332+0530 [WARN]  DB connection was unexpectedly closed; checking out a new one pg/lease_lock.go:222             appID=33bf14d5-cdf9-4531-a7d3-55ab8e8bc9cd err=leaseLock#GetLease failed: failed to begin transaction: sql: connection is already closed errVerbose=sql: connection is already closed
failed to begin transaction
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/pg.sqlxTransactionQ
        /mnt/d/D/Langs/Blockchain/transaction-checker/chainlink/core/services/pg/transaction.go:91
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/pg.(*leaseLock).getLease
        /mnt/d/D/Langs/Blockchain/transaction-checker/chainlink/core/services/pg/lease_lock.go:258
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/pg.(*leaseLock).loop
        /mnt/d/D/Langs/Blockchain/transaction-checker/chainlink/core/services/pg/lease_lock.go:220
runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1594
leaseLock#GetLease failed
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/pg.(*leaseLock).getLease
        /mnt/d/D/Langs/Blockchain/transaction-checker/chainlink/core/services/pg/lease_lock.go:291
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/pg.(*leaseLock).loop
        /mnt/d/D/Langs/Blockchain/transaction-checker/chainlink/core/services/pg/lease_lock.go:220
runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1594 logger=1.10.0@9b1c622.RunNode.LockedDB.LeaseLock
2022-12-13T13:31:48.536+0530 [DEBUG] evmclient.Client#CallContext RPC call success      client/node.go:945               args=["0x1c437b4",false] callName=CallContext duration=0.2095203 evmChainID=80001 logger=1.10.0@9b1c622.EVM.Node.RPC method=eth_getBlockByNumber mode=websocket node=(primary)primary-0-80001:wss://polished-divine-owl.matic-testnet.discover.quiknode.pro/API_KEY/ nodeName=primary-0-80001 nodeTier=primary requestID=REQUEST_ID rpcDomain=polished-divine-owl.matic-testnet.discover.quiknode.pro
2022-12-13T13:31:48.540+0530 [DEBUG] Fetching head                                      headtracker/head_tracker.go:331  blockHeight=29636531 evmChainID=80001 logger=1.10.0@9b1c622.EVM.HeadTracker
2022-12-13T13:31:48.541+0530 [DEBUG] RPC call: evmclient.Client#CallContext             client/node.go:426               args=["0x1c437b3",false] evmChainID=80001 logger=1.10.0@9b1c622.EVM.Node.RPC method=eth_getBlockByNumber mode=websocket node=(primary)primary-0-80001:wss://polished-divine-owl.matic-testnet.discover.quiknode.pro/API_KEY/ nodeName=primary-0-80001 nodeTier=primary requestID=154b805f-348b-415a-b728-d75743023962
2022-12-13T13:31:48.753+0530 [DEBUG] evmclient.Client#CallContext RPC call success      client/node.go:945               args=["0x1c437b3",false] callName=CallContext duration=0.2098329 evmChainID=80001 logger=1.10.0@9b1c622.EVM.Node.RPC method=eth_getBlockByNumber mode=websocket node=(primary)primary-0-80001:wss://polished-divine-owl.matic-testnet.discover.quiknode.pro/API_KEY/ nodeName=primary-0-80001 nodeTier=primary requestID=154b805f-348b-415a-b728-d75743023962 rpcDomain=polished-divine-owl.matic-testnet.discover.quiknode.pro
2022-12-13T13:31:48.757+0530 [DEBUG] Fetching head                                      headtracker/head_tracker.go:331  blockHeight=29636530 evmChainID=80001 logger=1.10.0@9b1c622.EVM.HeadTracker
2022-12-13T13:31:48.758+0530 [DEBUG] RPC call: evmclient.Client#CallContext             client/node.go:426               args=["0x1c437b2",false] evmChainID=80001 logger=1.10.0@9b1c622.EVM.Node.RPC method=eth_getBlockByNumber mode=websocket node=(primary)primary-0-80001:wss://polished-divine-owl.matic-testnet.discover.quiknode.pro/API_KEY/ nodeName=primary-0-80001 nodeTier=primary requestID=1b3ff8e7-4781-4319-bb70-69a709725fc8
2022-12-13T13:31:48.968+0530 [DEBUG] evmclient.Client#CallContext RPC call success      client/node.go:945               args=["0x1c437b2",false] callName=CallContext duration=0.209303 evmChainID=80001 logger=1.10.0@9b1c622.EVM.Node.RPC method=eth_getBlockByNumber mode=websocket node=(primary)primary-0-80001:wss://polished-divine-owl.matic-testnet.discover.quiknode.pro/API_KEY/ nodeName=primary-0-80001 nodeTier=primary requestID=1b3ff8e7-4781-4319-bb70-69a709725fc8 rpcDomain=polished-divine-owl.matic-testnet.discover.quiknode.pro
2022-12-13T13:31:48.974+0530 [DEBUG] Fetching head                                      headtracker/head_tracker.go:331  blockHeight=29636529 evmChainID=80001 logger=1.10.0@9b1c622.EVM.HeadTracker
2022-12-13T13:31:48.975+0530 [DEBUG] RPC call: evmclient.Client#CallContext             client/node.go:426               args=["0x1c437b1",false] evmChainID=80001 logger=1.10.0@9b1c622.EVM.Node.RPC method=eth_getBlockByNumber mode=websocket node=(primary)primary-0-80001:wss://polished-divine-owl.matic-testnet.discover.quiknode.pro/API_KEY/ nodeName=primary-0-80001 nodeTier=primary requestID=a364e758-2f45-47a7-afa7-87c70219b30e
2022-12-13T13:31:48.986+0530 [WARN]  DB connection was unexpectedly closed; checking out a new one pg/advisory_lock.go:178          advisoryLockID=1027321974924625846 err=sql: connection is already closed logger=1.10.0@9b1c622.RunNode.LockedDB.AdvisoryLock
2022-12-13T13:31:48.986+0530 [DEBUG] Taking advisory lock                               pg/advisory_lock.go:132          advisoryLockID=1027321974924625846 logger=1.10.0@9b1c622.RunNode.LockedDB.AdvisoryLock
2022-12-13T13:31:48.988+0530 [FATAL] Another node has taken the advisory lock, exiting immediately pg/advisory_lock.go:191          advisoryLockID=1027321974924625846 logger=1.10.0@9b1c622.RunNode.LockedDB.AdvisoryLock stacktrace=github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/pg.(*advisoryLock).loop
```

Is the problem related to advisory locks? Because, localhost:6688 responds for few seconds, then abruptly stops due to the error **db connection was unexpectedly closed**. Have been into this for around 2 days. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is the database server's log file?

Comment: I have uploaded the log file here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1piYstJLwtuIFDjbCoTjUVEdCgRu7Ir5XJjVy9Ndd3QY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I think that running PostgreSQL on WSL1 is not supported.  You could try running the native Windows PostgreSQL.

Comment: Updating WSL to version 2 will work? Because, to run chainlink node, I have to use postgres as a service from WSL itself.

Comment: Updating WSL to version 2 solved the issue for me. Thank you so much!